# Creating Static Values into a Sequelize model (no experience with migration)

Tags: node.js, model, sequelize.js

I am working on a group project that tests our use of Sequelize vs. normal ORM generated back-end items.  Two of our models in a MySQL DB are category tables.  These will not be dynamically created, updated or destroyed, but need to be there when the program runs.  The class I am a part of hasn't covered instances or migrations.  Here is the model thus far..

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
var maincategories = sequelize.define("maincategories", {
    maincategories_id: {
        //make primary key
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement:true
    },
    maincategories_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
},
    {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models){
                maincategories.hasMany(models.posts),
                maincategories.hasMany(models.subcategories)
            }
        }
    });

// maincategories.create({ maincategories_name: 'For Sale'}).then(function(insertedCategory){
//  console.log(insertedCategory.dataValues);
// });
maincategories.create({ maincategories_name: 'Housing'})
maincategories.create({ maincategories_name: 'Personals'});

return maincategories;
// maincategories.hasMany(posts);
// maincategories.hasMany(subcategories);
};
```

How can I get the Category table to have those values added to it at the time or prior to the node.js app starting?  Also, would the code reside in the model, api route or a separate file that is required in somewhere else?  As you can see I tried to do persistent instances but these did not work.  It would state that I had created these items in node CLI but nothing showed in the actual database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need maincategories.sync() in order for sequelize to sync the defined models to your db.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/sequelize/#syncoptions-promise